# Joomla MVC ORM that can handle many to many relation

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla3.0

It looks like Joomla MVC uses JTable as their ORM. Problem is that they can only handle one table and my application uses relational data.

Is it possible to use Joomla classes to map my Models to relational data or do I have to use a 3rd party for this (doctrine, propel)?

Not sure if this all makes sense because sometimes Joomla seems to use the JModel as a data provider (executing queries) and the JTable looks more like a model than JModel.

Comment: JTable does have some limitations. It would be useful if you could make describe your schema and what exactly your issue is. Like I have this object and I need to store it in the database, information spanning between 2-3 relational tables.

Comment: @ValentinDespa Thank you for your reply. If I have a link with id and name, category with id and name and link_name with link_id and name_id it's not possible to create this with a JTable. It is possible with a Model but have to enter all the sql statements myself.

Comment: You can use one JTable instance per table. You can map in JModel any associations and pass them to JTable on a per table basis.